# MySQL does not seem to store databases anywhere

Tags: mysql, sql

The MySQL command line works fine and connects well to PHP. However, the databases don't seem to be stored anywhere in the computer. I tried looking in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\` for the data folder, but there is none. I don't know if this is actually a problem or not but it is worrying me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get to your MySQL command line and run this query:

```
mysql> select @@datadir;
```

That's the location on your computer where it stores databases. The location can vary based on your configuration, but the query above will always tell you where it is.

Comment: It says `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data`.  But I cannot find it on my computer!

Comment: It's probably a "hidden folder". They think people shouldn't be allowed to view certain folders used by software. This is one of the reasons I don't use Windows anymore. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/cannot-see-program-data-file-in-c-drive-how-can-i/cce1748b-39bd-4ffc-8036-9b8dac2bacc8

Comment: Yes that's it, however all I had to do was type in `ProgramData` in the path directory of the "file finder" and it came up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check programdata folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL

Comment: I can't find it on my PC!

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the following command to get location of data folder

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE '%dir'
```